# MONGODB Failed to handshake with DB Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (TLS)

Tags: mongodb, ssl, production, mongodb-atlas, dev-to-production

I have a node.js app connected to a Mongo DB database,

I'm using the mongo URI link to connect from my web app.

I'm using DigitalOcean and I deployed the app to Heroku in order to check if I manage to avoid the:

**failed to handshake with Mongo Error**

for some reason, everything works great locally but when I deploy to production, I get this error accessing the production URL:

```
MONGODB Failed to handshake with db-shard-00-02-xyz.mongodb.net:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (db-shard-00-02-xyz.mongodb.net:27017, TLS)
```

My Heroku config file:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGODB_URI'] %>
      options:
        connect_timeout: 20
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to check if **your production IP is whitelisted** in order to be able to connect to your Mongo DB.

You can edit your mongo configuration on:

`cloud.mongodb.com > Network Access > IP Whitelist`

You can test if this is the issue by opening it to all:

`0.0.0.0/0`

hope it helps!

Comment: don't forget to remove `0.0.0.0/0` otherwise your database will be open to the world! instead use can use `curl ifconfig.me` to get your public ip and allow that.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, @David very helpful,

I will add a screenshot for those who need visual explanation:

[image: mongodb atlas configuration security panel:]

Comment: Found it with the accepted answer but thanks anyway :)